# Object lookup field not fetching values in wrapper class

Tags: apex, wrapper-class

I am using this below wrapper class in a method which is called from a action support from vf page.

In debug log - `@@@@offerId` --> Id of the record

But `@@@@offervalue` i am getting null. I am not sure why i am getting null..

```
public List<Wrapper> WrapperList {get;set;}

for( integer i=0 ; i < WrapperList.size(); i++ ) {
system.debug('@@@@offerId' + soWrapperList[i].soW.Testlookup__c);
 system.debug('@@@@offervalue' + soWrapperList[i].soW.Testlookup__r.Name);
}
```

Wrapper class -

```
 Public class Wrapper {
 public Test__c soW { get; set; }
 }
```

Comment: what data are you adding data into the wrapperList?

Comment: wrapperList .. i am using it as i am creating new rows...Testlookup__c is a lookup field.. which i am adding from vf page..

Answer (score 0):

when using a standard controller you don't get the values beyond the root object, create a query in your constructor to pull in the lookup values you require.

Select  id, name, Lookup_r.Name from Test__c where id=:Testid

Comment: That's not strictly true. It only queries fields that you statically reference, which can be relationships.